# Actualizar un elemento de forma dinamica

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo la siguiente duda ¿Hay otra forma de "actualizar" un elemento como una tabla? Por ejemplo, de esta tabla:

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="tbl">
<table>
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Supongamos que tiene muchos `th` y `td`. Si yo quisiera actualizarla podria hacerlo de las siguientes formas (que conozco usando `JQuery`):

```
// Primera forma: Remuevo toda la tabla y la creo desde cero otra vez
$("#tbl table").remove();
var new_tbl = "<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>";
$("#tbl").append(new_tbl); // Otra variante seria usar appendTo: $(new_tbl).appendTo("#tbl");

// Segundo forma: No elimino la tabla, sino la reemplzado usando .html()
var new_tbl = "<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>";
$("#tbl table").html(new_tbl);
```

Hasta ahora, he usado esas 2 formas y me iba normal, pero me di cuenta que cuando la tabla contiene muchos datos u otros elementos (tablas,botones,etc) dentro de ella. Al crearla usando esas formas, demora demasiado, por eso les quiero preguntar si hay otra forma de actualizarla (Lo hago por JQuery para hacerlo dinamico y no tener que recargar la pagina)

Comment: Saludos. Considero que el código que muestras (aunque omites el generar el/los `th`/`tr` y su contenido -ojo en `thead` es `th` en `tbody` es `tr`-) no debe demorar mucho; puede ser que la cantidad de datos a desplegar sea lo tardado, otra posibilidad es la forma en que obtengas los datos que vacías a `table`; es decir si realizar muchas peticiones al servidor para poblar todos los datos que muestra en cada momento; incluso si recibes objetos que no usas (ya sean propiedades o que filtras y no presentas).

Comment: @RobertoLeOr Tengo una tabla con 600 datos, cada `td` que contiene otra tabla independiente, dentro de esta tabla, cada `td`, contiene un `button` con `dropdown`, al crearse esto demora mucho, por eso busco otra forma de actualizar. Es como decir tengo una tabla con muchas tablas en cada td, y en cada td tengo muchos buttons dropdowns

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que utilices Datatables.

Es un plugin especificamente creado para trabajar con tablas de todo tipo. Tiene muchísimas opciones y métodos, es altamente customizable y es multinavegador.

https://datatables.net/

Tiene además buena documentación y hay una comunidad muy activa en la solución de bugs y otros.

Comment: Se puede hace un calendario usando datatable? Digo calendario porque ahi se puede crear eventos, etc

Comment: En ese caso no es mejor un plugin ??

Comment: @JuanRivera, se pueden utilizar uno/varios datepicker en las celdas de la tabla perfectamente.

Comment: Tratare de implementarlo, porque lo que quiero hacer es una calendario muy personalizado, donde el `thead` seran los dias y el `tbody` estara toda la informacion